# Elegant way for element operation with for-loops on Eigen3 matrix, using modern C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, eigen3

I want to do some operation with elements in a matrix, depending on the position of each element.

I know that by-default, Eigen matrix is column-major, so to loop over the matrix, the outer for-loop is for each column, and the inner for-loop is for each row. I have 4 kinds of expressions to be assigned to `m(r,c)`, depending on the values of `r` and `c`. Some pseudo-code is shown below:

```
if c == some_c
    if r == some_r
        m(r,c) = some expression A
    else
        m(r,c) = some expression B
else
    if r == some_r
        m(r,c) = some expression C
    else
        m(r,c) = some expression D
```

I have also made detailed c++ codes below. I am not C++ expert, so I am not sure whether my code is elegant or not. Could you please let me know how to improve it? I would prefer using possible modern C++14 or C++17 features.

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using Matrix = Eigen::MatrixXd

void some_operation_on_matrix(Matrix& m, size_t some_r, size_t some_c)
{
    for (size_t c = 0; c < m.cols(); c++) {
        for (size_t r = 0; r < m.rows(); r++) {
            if (c == some_c) {
                if (r == some_r) {
                    // m(r,c) = some expression A
                }
                else {
                    // m(r,c) = some expression B
                }
            }
            else {
                if (r == some_r) {
                    // m(r,c) = some expression C
                }
                else {
                    // m(r,c) = some expression D
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "I am not sure whether my code is elegant or not"  close the file, dont open it for a week, then open it and try to understand what you wrote ;). Or ask someone else to read it. You might want to move the question to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, as asking for code reviews is considered off topic here (for being too broad and/or opinion-based or whatever)

Comment: but note that codereview is for working code and also here it is imho a bit pointless to ask for the elegancy of code that does nothing. Of course writing only the comments, but not the code isnt very elegant :P

Comment: btw I dont know eigen, but it might be more efficient to split the operation into two, one that you apply to all the elements and one that you apply only to the ones in row `some_r` and in column `some_c`

Comment: Does `some expression X` change/depend on `r`, `c`? I.e., is your matrix constant, except for one row and one column?

Comment: @chtz, my matrix is not constant. `some expression` is the result of computations on `m(r,c)` and other entries in the matrix.

Comment: @user463035818, thanks for directing me to a website dedicated for code reviewing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change the logic of your loop a bit

```
void some_operation_on_matrix(Matrix& m, size_t some_r, size_t some_c)
{
    for (size_t c = 0; c < m.cols(); c++) {
        if (c == some_c) {
            for (size_t r = 0; r < m.rows(); r++) {
                if (r == some_r) {
                    // m(r,c) = some expression A
                }
                else {
                    // m(r,c) = some expression B
                }
            }
        else {
            for (size_t r = 0; r < m.rows(); r++) {
                if (r == some_r) {
                    // m(r,c) = some expression C
                }
                else {
                    // m(r,c) = some expression D
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thus, the if statement `if (c == some_c)` has only to be evaluated for all `m.cols` and not for all `m.cols * m.rows`.

You can extract the second for loop in a function

```
void innerLoop(Matrix &m, const size_t some_r, std::function expression1, std::function expression2)
{
    for (size_t r = 0; r < m.rows(); r++) {
        if (r == some_r) {
            m(r,c) = expression1(...);
        }
        else {
            m(r,c) = expression2(...);
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
void some_operation_on_matrix(Matrix& m, size_t some_r, size_t some_c)
{
    for (size_t c = 0; c < m.cols(); c++) {
        if (c == some_c) {
            innerLoop(m, some_r, expressionA, expressionB);
        else {
            innerLoop(m, some_r, expressionC, expressionC);           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ymmv, but my first priority is readability, and I dont consider this more readable than OPs code. Also i consider "not repeating myself" as an important part of elegancy, but you have some major code duplication (though not worse than in OPs code). Anyhow, I believe this question does not belong here because there is no one good answer, but only opinion-based suggestions

Comment: Any decent compiler will most likely hoist the `c` comparison out of the inner loop. [Example](https://godbolt.org/g/hYMkGo) (note the two separate calls to `m.rows()` in the assembly). This code transformation is thus very unlikely to have any benefit to offset the loss of readability.

Comment: @schorsch312, thanks for your examples. Nice idea to extract the inner loop out as a function.

Comment: @MaxLanghof, thanks for pointing out the work of compiler. Good knowledge to gain.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using a lambda functor:

```
void some_operation_on_matrix(Eigen::MatrixXd& out, int some_r, int some_c)
{
  out = Eigen::MatrixXd::NullaryExpr(out.rows(), out.cols(),
    [&](Eigen::Index r, Eigen::Index c)
    {
        if(c == some_c)
            if(r == some_r)
                return 1.0; // some expr A
            else
                return 2.0; // some expr B
        else
            if(r == some_r)
                return 3.0; // some expr C
            else
                return 4.0; // some expr D 
     });
}
```

Probably more efficient (if all expressions are constant) would be

```
out.setConstant(D);
out.row(some_r).setConstant(C);
out.col(some_c).setConstant(B);
out(some_r, some_c) = A;
```

Comment: Oh, great idea. Never thought this before. I will learn more about how to use lambda functor!